How do I move checked items from left list to the right list and the opposite by JS
[enter image description here][1]
Hi, I want to create 2 lists like the attached image that can move items from the left list to the right list and the opposite by JavaScript. my code for moving all items is correct but for checked items, it doesn't work and I couldn't find my problem to solve it. Please help me, thanks.
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/kQVRb.png
my HTML code is:
<div class="container">
   <div class="side left-side"></div>
   <div class="mid-side">
     <button class="all-to-right">>></button>
     <button class="checked-to-right">></button>
     <button class="checked-to-left"><</button>
     <button class="all-to-left"><<</button>
   </div>
   <div class="side right-side"></div>
 </div> 

and my JS code is:
const leftSide = document.querySelector(".left-side");
const rightSide = document.querySelector(".right-side");

// Initial Values
let leftList = [
  { id: "item1", checked: false, title: "PHP" },
  { id: "item2", checked: false, title: "Python" },
  { id: "item3", checked: false, title: "Ruby" },
  { id: "item4", checked: false, title: "C++" },
];
let rightList = [
  { id: "item5", checked: false, title: "HTML" },
  { id: "item6", checked: false, title: "CSS" },
  { id: "item7", checked: false, title: "JavaScript" },
  { id: "item8", checked: false, title: "Java" },
];

// Render Dom
function renderDom(leftListToRender, rightListToRender) {
  // Clear previous content
  leftSide.innerHTML = "";
  rightSide.innerHTML = "";

  // Render items in left list
  leftListToRender.forEach((item) => {
    leftSide.innerHTML += `<div class="box">
        <input type="checkbox" class="input-box" id="${item.id}" />
        <label for="${item.id}">${item.title}</label>
        </div>`;
  });

  // Render items in right list
  rightListToRender.forEach((item) => {
    rightSide.innerHTML += `<div class="box">
          <input type="checkbox" class="input-box" id="${item.id}" />
          <label for="${item.id}">${item.title}</label>
          </div>`;
  });

  // Register event listeners
  registerEvents();
}

// Clear Dom
function clearDom() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".side").forEach((el) => {
    el.innerHTML = "";
  });
}

// Move all items from left to right
// ....
};

// Move all items from right to left
// ....

// Move checked items from right to left
document.querySelector(".checked-to-left").onclick = function () {
  const checkedItems = rightList.filter((item) => item.checked);
  leftList = leftList.concat(checkedItems);
  rightList = rightList.filter((item) => !item.checked);
  renderDom(leftList, rightList);
  checkButtonCondition();
};

// Move checked items from left to right
document.querySelector(".checked-to-right").onclick = function () {
  const checkedItems = leftList.filter((item) => item.checked);
  rightList = rightList.concat(checkedItems);
  leftList = leftList.filter((item) => !item.checked);
  renderDom(leftList, rightList);
  checkButtonCondition();

};

// Check button conditions
function checkButtonCondition() {
  const allToLeftBtn = document.querySelector(".all-to-left");
  const checkedToRightBtn = document.querySelector(".checked-to-right");
  const checkedToLeftBtn = document.querySelector(".checked-to-left");
  const allToRightBtn = document.querySelector(".all-to-right");

  if (leftList.length === 0) {
    allToRightBtn.classList.add("disabled");
    checkedToRightBtn.classList.add("disabled");
  } else {
    allToRightBtn.classList.remove("disabled");
    checkedToRightBtn.classList.remove("disabled");
  }

  if (rightList.length === 0) {
    allToLeftBtn.classList.add("disabled");
    checkedToLeftBtn.classList.add("disabled");
  } else {
    allToLeftBtn.classList.remove("disabled");
    checkedToLeftBtn.classList.remove("disabled");
  }
}

// Register event listeners
function registerEvents() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".input-box").forEach((checkbox) => {
    checkbox.addEventListener("change", function () {
      checkButtonCondition();
    });
  });
}

// Initial rendering
renderDom(leftList, rightList);
checkButtonCondition();


Please define "it doesn't work". What goes wrong for checked items? Notice, that the HTML of buttons is invalid, you need to use HTML entities to show < and > (&lt; and &gt;).

when clicking on the bottom to move the checked item to the left or checked item to the right, my functions for "onclick" don't work, and checked items don't move to another list. By the way, thanks for your tip to use HTML entities and I will definitely use it.

Just fixing the entity issue might fix your problem too. Actually it's amazing how browsers render that correctly.

I used it but doesn't fix.

You can use append to just move the box directly from one parent div to another. You don't have to rewrite the whole html every time with innerHTML. It's also a bit cleaner if you don't write your HTML as strings in javascript.


const leftlist = document.querySelector("#leftlist")
const rightlist = document.querySelector("#rightlist")
const btnright = document.querySelector("#moveright")
const btnleft = document.querySelector("#moveleft")

btnright.addEventListener("click", () => moveCheckedItems(leftlist, rightlist))
btnleft.addEventListener("click",  () => moveCheckedItems(rightlist, leftlist))


function moveCheckedItems(targetList, destinationList){
    const currentItems = targetList.querySelectorAll(".box")
    for(let box of currentItems) {
      if(box.querySelector("input").checked) {
         destinationList.append(box)
      }
    }
}
input, body, button {
  font-size:1em;
  padding:2px;
}
#wrapper {
    display:flex;
    margin:5px;
}

#leftlist, #rightlist {
  border:2px solid grey;
  padding:5px;
}
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="leftlist">
      <div class="box">
          <input type="checkbox" class="input-box" id="box1" />
          <label for="box1">PHP</label>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
          <input type="checkbox" class="input-box" id="box1" />
          <label for="box1">JS</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightlist">
      <div class="box">
          <input type="checkbox" class="input-box" id="box1" />
          <label for="box1">Python</label>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
          <input type="checkbox" class="input-box" id="box1" />
          <label for="box1">Ruby</label>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
<button id="moveright">
  Move checked items from left to right
</button>
</div>
<div>
<button id="moveleft">
  Move checked items from right to left
</button>
</div>



